# MiniProfiler plus EntityFramework plus EFProviderWrapperToolkit?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, mvc-mini-profiler

Is it possible to use the MiniProfiler 1.9 with EntityFramework and also with EFProviderWrapperToolkit?  I'm also using the update edmx from database method, not code first.

I have EFProviderWrapperToolkit already installed and working very well, it's caching provider makes a big difference.  But it seems to clash with the MiniProfiler:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (Request.IsLocal)
    {
        //MiniProfiler.Start();
        MiniProfilerEF.Initialize();
    }
}
```

It is probably because both MiniProfiler and EFProviderWrapperToolkit are attempting to wrap the 
db connection.

Gives this error message:

> Unable to cast object of type 'MvcMiniProfiler.Data.EFProfiledDbConnection' 
>       to type 'EFProviderWrapperToolkit.DbConnectionWrapper'.
>
> Line 229: DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(invariantName); 
>       Line 230: var connectionWrapper = factory.CreateConnection(); 
>       Line 231: DbConnectionWrapper wrapper = (DbConnectionWrapper)connectionWrapper; 
>       Line 232: wrapper.WrappedConnection = connection; 
>       Line 233: connection = connectionWrapper;
>
> [InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'MvcMiniProfiler.Data.EFProfiledDbConnection' to type 'EFProviderWrapperToolkit.DbConnectionWrapper'.]
>          EFProviderWrapperToolkit.DbConnectionWrapper.WrapConnection(DbConnection connection, String[] wrapperProviderInvariantNames) in C:\src\MyApp.2010\EF4ProviderWrappers\EFProviderWrapperToolkit\DbConnectionWrapper.cs:231
>          EFProviderWrapperToolkit.EntityConnectionWrapperUtils.CreateEntityConnectionWithWrappers(String entityConnectionString, EntityConnectionStringBuilder ecsb, String[] wrapperProviders) in C:\src\MyApp.2010\EF4ProviderWrappers\EFProviderWrapperToolkit\EntityConnectionWrapperUtils.cs:60
>          MyApp.Infrastructure.Repository.EF.ExtendedMyAppContext..ctor(String connectionString, EntityConnectionStringBuilder ecsb) in C:\src\MyApp.2010\MyApp.Infrastructure.Repository.EF\ExtendedMyAppContext.cs:19
>          MyApp.Infrastructure.Repository.EF.ObjectContextManager.GetObjectContext() in C:\src\MyApp.2010\MyApp.Infrastructure.Repository.EF\Repository.EF\ObjectContextManager.cs:62
>          MyApp.Infrastructure.Repository.EF.GenericRepository`1.get_ObjectContext() in C:\src\MyApp.2010\MyApp.Infrastructure.Repository.EF\Repository.EF\GenericRepository.cs:81
>          MyApp.Infrastructure.Repository.EF.GenericRepository`1.get_ObjectSet() in C:\src\MyApp.2010\MyApp.Infrastructure.Repository.EF\Repository.EF\GenericRepository.cs:89
>          MyApp.Infrastructure.Repository.EF.GenericRepository`1.GetQuery() in C:\src\MyApp.2010\MyApp.Infrastructure.Repository.EF\Repository.EF\GenericRepository.cs:102

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without modifying either of them the answer is no because they both replace database provider but those replacements are not compatible.